# VBA to put SUMIFS in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell, sumifs

I wrote code to put SUMIFs in a cell based on sheet name. newFileName and oldFileName are declared variables used as sheet names.

```
Sheets(newFileName).Select
Range("C2").Formula = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets(oldFileName).Range("$G:$G"), Sheets(oldFileName).Range("F:F"), Range("B2"))
```

This works!

However, I want to put the SUMIFS formula in cell C2

```
Sheets(newFileName).Select
Range("C2").Formula = "=SumIfs(Sheets(oldFileName).Range("$G:G"), Sheets(oldFileName).Range("F:F"), Range("B2"))"
```

This gives a compile error. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the formula in formula syntax, which means `'` before and after the sheet name and `!` before the ranges. More importantly, a formula is just a `String` so you should not be using `Sheets` or `Range` calls when constructing it:

```vb
Sheets(newFileName).Range("C2").Formula = "=SumIfs('" & oldFileName & "'!G:G,'" & oldFileName & "'!F:F,B2)"
```